# Using JQuery .animate() to start when the previous ALMOST end?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I'm trying to start a new animation when the first animation is close to his end.
i know how i can start a new one when the previous is fully ended:

```
$("#clickme").click(function () {
    $("#book").animate({
        opacity: 0.25,
        left: "+=50",
        height: "toggle"
    }, 5000, function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

so if the animation is taking 5 seconds than start the second one in 3 seconds (or something like that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a delay, maybe?

```
$("#book").animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=50",
    height: "toggle"
}, 5000).delay(3000).fadeOut();
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting a little fancy pancy and creating a custom animation method that lets you specify the delay before the callback should be called, instead of calling it once the animation has completed.
It's still based on the completion of the animation, so it's more reliable than just using a timeout.

```
$.fn.Ani = function(props, duration, callback, delay_callback) {
    return (function(elem) {
        var calledBack = false;
        return elem.animate(props, {
            progress: function(o, elapsed) {
                var per = (delay_callback / duration).toFixed(2),
                    ela = elapsed.toFixed(2);

                if (ela > per && !(calledBack)) {
                    calledBack = true;
                    callback(ela);
                }
            },
            duration: duration
        });
    })(this);
}
```

And you can use it like :

```
$("#clickme").click(function () {
    $("#book").Ani({
        opacity: 0.25,
        left: "+=50",
        height: "toggle"
    }, 5000, function(triggered_at) { // animation duration  = 5000
        console.log(triggered_at) // shows the percentage when callback triggered
    }, 3000); // delay before triggering callback = 3000
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MLAe6/1/)